# Start spacemacs with specific layout open

Tags: spacemacs

I have a custom layout, which I can open with `SPC l o f`. Is there a way to start Emacs with a flag that would automatically load it at startup? I tried this way: `emacs --eval '(persp-switch "Asd")'` but it yields an error: `Wrong type argument: hash-table-p, nil`. I've also tried with `"Default"` with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

you can't switch perspectives until the according elisp code is loaded… and command-line evals are evaluated immediately, before anything else.  so **don't** do it as an eval in the cmd line, but do it as the **last command** in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

Comment: …correction: as the last command in ~/.emacs.d/init.el.